# InDesign Server (5.5), pdf preset do not seem to work

Tags: java, adobe-indesign

I'm a bloody beginner with InDesign Server and stumbled upon a problem applying PDF presets to my document as described here in chapter 3.3 (page #56):

```
OptPDFExportPreset optPreset = OptArg.noPDFExportPreset();
PDFExportPreset preset = 
        myApp.getNamedChildPDFExportPreset("[Press Quality]");
if (preset != null) {
    optPreset = OptArg.makePDFExportPreset(preset);
} else {
    // imagine error logging here
}
```

I played around with the preset names, applied "[]" and ".joboption", unluckily none of the stuff worked.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: After digging through the manual/api docs I found the following helpful code, which I applied to my error logging:

```
for (PDFExportPreset preset : myApp.getAllChildPDFExportPresets()) {
    LOGGER.error(preset.getFullName() + " " + preset.getName());
}
```

which spit out the following list

```
2012-03-07 10:13:37,034 ERROR org.zcore.common.pdfcreator.PDFCreator.createPDF(PDFCreator.java:161) - /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe PDF/Settings/High Quality Print.joboptions [Qualitativ hochwertiger Druck]
2012-03-07 10:13:37,038 ERROR org.zcore.common.pdfcreator.PDFCreator.createPDF(PDFCreator.java:161) - /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe PDF/Settings/PDFX1a 2001.joboptions [PDF/X-1a:2001]
2012-03-07 10:13:37,046 ERROR org.zcore.common.pdfcreator.PDFCreator.createPDF(PDFCreator.java:161) - /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe PDF/Settings/PDFX3 2002.joboptions [PDF/X-3:2002]
2012-03-07 10:13:37,052 ERROR org.zcore.common.pdfcreator.PDFCreator.createPDF(PDFCreator.java:161) - /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe PDF/Settings/PDFX4 2008.joboptions [PDF/X-4:2008]
2012-03-07 10:13:37,060 ERROR org.zcore.common.pdfcreator.PDFCreator.createPDF(PDFCreator.java:161) - /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe PDF/Settings/Press Quality.joboptions [Druckausgabequalität]
2012-03-07 10:13:37,066 ERROR org.zcore.common.pdfcreator.PDFCreator.createPDF(PDFCreator.java:161) - /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe PDF/Settings/screen_pdf.joboptions [screen_pdf]
2012-03-07 10:13:37,072 ERROR org.zcore.common.pdfcreator.PDFCreator.createPDF(PDFCreator.java:161) - /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe PDF/Settings/Smallest File Size.joboptions [Kleinste Dateigröße]
```

which brought me to the conclusion the whole stuff is localized. [screen_pdf] worked pretty fine so far, but unluckily any String used german umlauts/ligature (öäüß) throws an exception within CORBA.

Comment: The easiest way around this seems to be re-creating the joboptions and don't use any non-ANSI chars. I still wonder if there's a legit way using UTF8 chars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unluckily there is no answer to this; Adobe is aware of this problem and does not have any intention of fixing this.